# Use ADL swap of base class

Tags: c++, c++11

For the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Base {
    friend void swap(Base&, Base&)
    {
        std::cout << "base swap\n";
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {};

int main()
{
    Derived d1, d2;

    using std::swap;
    swap(d1, d2);
}
```

When I try to use ADL swap on `Derived` objects, the swap function for `Base` is not invoked. Instead, `std::swap` is used. Do I have to write a separate ADL swap for `Derived`? What's the best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `swap` in base is considered, but the `std::swap` is considered a better match as it requires no conversion to base.

Here is a stab at it:

```
struct Base {
  template<class T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, T>{}, int> =0
  >
  friend void swap(T&, T&) {
    std::cout << "base swap\n";
  }
};
```

Sadly, this doesn't work, as it has the *exact* same overload "strength" as `std::swap` does and we get ambiguity.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/984b742eaa4e87c4).

I am unaware of a way to create such a swap-in-base that doesn't run afoul of that pitfall.

Possibly concepts will give us the power we need to make the friend swap "more specialized" than the `std::swap`.

Answer (score 1):

As **Yakk** said, there is no way to make a more specialized function than `std::swap`. But we could make our own.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

struct Base {
    template<
        class T,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, T>{}, int> = 0
    >
    friend void adl_swap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
        std::cout << "base swap\n";
    }
};

struct Derived : Base {};


template<
    class T,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<Base, T>{}, int> = 0
>
void adl_swap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
    std::cout << "std::swap\n";
    using std::swap;
    swap(lhs, rhs);
}


int main() {
    Derived d1, d2;
    adl_swap(d1, d2); // output : base swap

    int a{1}, b{2};
    adl_swap(a,b); // output : std::swap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to provide a `swap` function for derived types in the base class is to forward that aforementioned types to the later using the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Base {
    friend void swap(Base&, Base&) {
        std::cout << "base swap" << std::endl;
    }
    friend void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {  // Preferred over std::swap
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(lhs), static_cast<Base&>(rhs));
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived> {};

int main() {
    Derived d1, d2;

    using std::swap;
    swap(d1, d2);
}
```

This works because direct overloads of the function are preferred over templated ones as **Yakk** explained in his response.

This solution won't work if that `Base` class is meant for use in traditional polymorphism though.